# Scale the shape but no text within

Tags: css, text, raphael, scale, zooming

I have built a Raphael app which creates shapes, gets some numbers from DB and displays it in the middle of the shapes, and at the end created a clone of the shape on top, make it invisible (`'opacity': 0`) and is clickable.

I have added a zooming functionality either, and all works fine.

All are being zoomed with the text which *shouldn't* be re-scaled. What way can I stop the text which is on the same paper as the shape from being scaled?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a fixed size in px for your text, like this:

```
.element {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

This was the very first thing have done trying to resolve it. Added !important as well but not working...

Thanks